# Restricting Characters on Sage

Tags: computational-mathematics, characters, computer-algebra-systems, sagemath, computational-algebra

I am using Sage to obtain the character table of different permutation groups using the command *G.character_table()*. Is there any implemented command in Sage that restricts an irreducible character (ie, row of the table) to a given subgroup?

Alternatively, as I am mainly interested in Sylow $p$-subgroups, is it possible to delete from the character table all conjugacy classes whose order is not a power of $p$? I have been doing this manually using *G.conjugacy_classes()* and working out which conjugacy classes have order a power $p$ as I did not manage to write a code that works out the order of the conjugacy classes.

Comment: It's probably better to ask this at ask.sagemath.org or the sage-support Google group, since it's a software question, not a math question.